# How to create new Power BI table where each column (except date) is converted into new rows with duplicated date

Tags: powerbi, dax

I want to extract data from a table in power BI such that all column titles form a new row for each date. For example, say I have the following table:

| Date | Apples | Bananas | Cucumbers |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 31 Jan 2024 | 50 | 40 | 20 |
| 29 Feb 2024 | 40 | 30 | 20 |

And I want to make a new table like this:

| Date | Things | Prices |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 31 Jan 2024 | Apples | 50 |
| 31 Jan 2024 | Bananas | 40 |
| 31 Jan 2024 | Cucumbers | 20 |
| 29 Feb 2024 | Apples | 40 |
| 29 Feb 2024 | Bananas | 30 |
| 29 Feb 2024 | Cucumbers | 20 |

Is there a way to do this?

I tried using Dax code but haven't gotten any progress so far.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For each fruit/vegetable column I create a temporary table with columns for the date, the name of the fruit/vegetable as "Things", and its corresponding value in the "Prices" column.
Then, I use UNION to combine these temporary tables into a single table and unpivot your original table.

```
  UnpivotedTable = 
    UNION(
        SELECTCOLUMNS(
            MyTable,
            "Date", MyTable[Date],
            "Things", "Apples",
            "Prices", MyTable[Apples]
        ),
        SELECTCOLUMNS(
            MyTable,
            "Date", MyTable[Date],
            "Things", "Bananas",
            "Prices", MyTable[Bananas]
        ),
        SELECTCOLUMNS(
            MyTable,
            "Date", MyTable[Date],
            "Things", "Cucumbers",
            "Prices", MyTable[Cucumbers]
        )
    )
```

[image]